# split up a matrix in matrices by value of column nodes in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this in R:

```
          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]         [,4]            [,5]   
19992    -33.54971    23.35746    0.0000000    2.107680e+01    19980219
19993    -33.54203    23.40079    0.0000000    2.107696e+01    19980219
19994    -33.53453    23.44445    0.0000000    2.107713e+01    19980219
19995    -33.52719    23.48840    0.0000000    2.107730e+01    19980219
19996    -33.51965    23.53200    0.0000000    2.107746e+01    19980219
19997    -33.51183    23.57565    0.0000000    2.107763e+01    19980219
19998    -33.50446    23.61958    0.0000000    2.107780e+01    19980219
19999    -33.49678    23.66313    0.0000000    2.107796e+01    19980219
```

Its actually a lot bigger (2.000.000 rows) but I think that this example will do for my question.

I want to extract all rows that have a value between e.g. -33.52... and -33.55... in the first column and create a new matrix of these extracted rows.

The output matrix would than be for example:

```
19992    -33.54971    23.35746    0.0000000    2.107680e+01    19980219
19993    -33.54203    23.40079    0.0000000    2.107696e+01    19980219
19994    -33.53453    23.44445    0.0000000    2.107713e+01    19980219
19995    -33.52719    23.48840    0.0000000    2.107730e+01    19980219
```

Some tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data, we can do something like this

```
txt <- 
" -33.54971    23.35746    0.0000000    2.107680e+01    19980219
 -33.54203    23.40079    0.0000000    2.107696e+01    19980219
 -33.53453    23.44445    0.0000000    2.107713e+01    19980219
 -33.52719    23.48840    0.0000000    2.107730e+01    19980219
 -33.51965    23.53200    0.0000000    2.107746e+01    19980219
 -33.51183    23.57565    0.0000000    2.107763e+01    19980219
 -33.50446    23.61958    0.0000000    2.107780e+01    19980219
 -33.49678    23.66313    0.0000000    2.107796e+01    19980219"

mat <- matrix(scan(text = txt), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
cond <- mat[,1] < -33.52 & mat[,1] > -33.55
mat[cond, ]

##         [,1]   [,2] [,3]   [,4]     [,5]
## [1,] -33.550 23.357    0 21.077 19980219
## [2,] -33.542 23.401    0 21.077 19980219
## [3,] -33.535 23.444    0 21.077 19980219
## [4,] -33.527 23.488    0 21.077 19980219
```

Comment: Oops! I think this is the right answer (between -33.52 and -33.55)

Comment: Thats it! Thx for the help and quick respsonses dickoa and others!

Answer (score 2):

Assume your original matrix is called `the_matrix`. To get those row indices whose values in the first column are in the specified range you can use

```
ind <- which( the_matrix[, 1] < -33.52 & the_matrix[, 1] > -33.55 )
```

To create the new matrix with only these rows, use

```
new_matrix <- the_matrix[ind, ]
```

Comment: sieste, The comparison should be the other way. Check @dickoa's answer. that is, > -33.55 and < -33.52.

Answer (score 2):

Use logical comparison which you can use to subset like this:

```
set.seed(1096)
m <- matrix( runif(36,-30,30) , ncol = 6 )
m
            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -10.8645147  12.701539 11.830714  12.027012  13.007876 -27.569211
[2,] -27.7127809 -20.907217 26.667036 -16.142388  20.287297  12.283898
[3,]   8.1607388  13.326040 -8.937501   2.541782   2.705917  18.490514
[4,]  14.0729963   4.522238 13.869731  13.708621 -22.996189  29.276250
[5,]  -0.3717591  18.057403 18.940814   3.430272 -23.460082 -27.296111
[6,] -14.0079398  -7.932984 24.836415 -20.442637  20.630987   8.138304

m[ m[,1] > -15 & m[,1] < -10 , ]
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]     [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -10.86451 12.701539 11.83071  12.02701 13.00788 -27.569211
[2,] -14.00794 -7.932984 24.83641 -20.44264 20.63099   8.138304
```

We put our condition to subset on in the rows position in the `[` operator (note the `,` after the conditions in the last command above, with nothing after it we are telling R to return all columns).

We add our conditions to subset on use the `&` operator to chain conditions together, so in this case we only want rows with values in the first column ( `m[,1]` ) that are greater than -15 `&` less than -10.

You might say

```
m[ (some condition) , c(1,2) ]
```

And if `(some condition)` is an expression that R can evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` it will return only rows that evaluate to `TRUE`. And this time we ask for *only* columns 1 and 2 (we could also say `1:2` )

Comment: (+1). no need for `which` here.

Comment: @Arun thanks. I added some more explanations because I want the answer to be more useful to others who want to understand this kind of simple subsetting.

Comment: Very nice usage of `>` with -15 and `<` with -10, thus taking care of signs.